# Showing the convergence of a difference equation?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have some variable $x_t$ which is the value of $x$ at time step $t$. Now, half the time I update it by adding $0.05$ and the other half of the time I update it by multiplying it by $0.95$. These two events are independent. Mathematically we have:

\begin{align}
x_t=x_{t-1}+0.05 \\
x_t=x_{t-1}*0.95
\end{align}

As $t$ approaches infinity, the value of $x$ approaches $1$, I know this from just plugging numbers in. We see that $x$ will always converge to $1$.

For example, suppose I start at $1.5$, after one time step we add $0.05$ which results in $1.55$. At the next time step, we might add $0.05$ or multiply by $0.95$, for simplicity, let's say we oscillate between the two. That is, on the next time step we multiply by $0.95$ and get $1.4725$. Now we add $0.05$ and get $1.5225$. Then we add multiply by $0.95$ and get $1.45$. If you do this enough you hover around $1$.

Another way to think of it is like this. Suppose I had a fair coin with faces head and tails. If it lands on heads, then I update the variable $x$ by adding $0.05$. If it lands on tails, then I update the variable $x$ by multiplying it by $0.95$. If I flip the coins enough times, the expected value of $x$ will approach $1$.

Is there a way to prove this and show that the expected value of $x$ is around $1$? What area of mathematics deals with problems like these? Could this just be some sort of series in disguise?

Comment: So, $$x_{2t+2} = 0.95 x_{2t+1} = 0.95(x_{2t}+0.05) = 0.95 x_{2t} + 0.0475$$ and $$x_{2t+3} = x_{2t+2} +0.05 = 0.95 x_{2t+1}+0.05$$? (The order and what exactly you mean by "half the time" and "the other half of the time' seem to matter to define the sequence...)

Comment: Unless you mean a stochastic rule ("independently, at each step $t$, apply one of the two rules, with equal probability $1/2$"? Which would explain the tag [probability], but still leave a lot of room for doubts.) Please, clarify your question...

Comment: @Justin Liang It is impossible for a sequence to converge if it increases by $0.05$ infinitely often.

Comment: @Clement Yeah, it follows the stochastic rule you mentioned, the probability that it will apply rule one versus rule two are independent events.

Comment: @ErickWong Maybe I should rephrase it to what is the expected value of $x$? Would that be more clear?

Comment: Please, edit your question accordingly, then. It is not obvious at all what you are currently asking. @JustinLiang

Comment: And yes, you may want to consider the sequence of expectations... they should satisfy something along the lines of $e_{t+1} = \frac{39}{40}e_t + 0.025$ (at first glance).

Comment: @JustinLiang Well, the expected value of $x$ converges to $1$ but that is much weaker than your original statement (e.g. a variable that oscillates between $-100$ and $102$ also has expected value $1$, but you can hardly say it hovers around $1$).  That's why it's critical that you try to make precise what phenomenon you are asking about.

Comment: "If I flip the coins enough times, the value of x will approach 1." No it will not. But, under this model, the expectations $e_t=E(x_t)$ then solve $$e_{t+1}=\frac12(e_t+0.05)+\frac12(e_t\cdot0.95),$$ from which one deduces that $$e_{t+1}-1=(1-0.025)\cdot(e_t-1),$$ hence indeed, for every initial condition $x_0$, $$\lim E(x_t)=1.$$

Comment: @Did How did you show that the lim$e_t=1$? Do you just assume that $e_{t+1}$ converges to $e_{t}$ so you set the two equal and solve?

Comment: Not at all. Rather I solve $u_{t+1}=au_t$ as $u_t=a^tu_0$ hence, if $|a|<1$, $u_t\to0$ for every $u_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your two equations reduce to $x_{i+2} = x_{i}*0.95+0.05$. We can just drop the "+2" in favor of "+1": $x_{i+1} = x_{i}*0.95+0.05$.  Now, we get convergence iff $x_{i+1} \rightarrow x_i$.  So we set $x_{i+1}=x_i\equiv x$ to see if we can get a convergence.  The resulting equation is $x=.95x+.05$.  This is solved by your result.

Comment: The order in which the rules are applied matter, your formula does not seem correct to me (one should get a different relation for even and odd $t$'s, I think).

Comment: Hmm this approach seems to make sense, since half the time we add $0.05$ and half the time we multiply by $0.95$, the expected value two time steps ahead would just be $x_{i+2}=x_i*0.95+0.05$.

Comment: @JustinLiang Nope, according to Clement's calculation, the expected value after *two* time steps is $0.950625 x_i + 0.0519395$.  Note that order matters so clearly $0.95x + 0.05$ is too simplistic: why should a stochastic process prefer $0.95x + 0.05$ over $0.95(x + 0.05)$?

Comment: OK, if we need to know each $i$ value, it matters.  But if we just want the limit, which was his question, an infinite series  step 1, step 2, step 1, .... will end up in exactly the same place as step 2, step 1, step 2 ...  Maybe I should have been more explicit about this.  Try: Start with $x_1$ equal to some number (OP has made no mention of specifics) and we get $x_2$ and proceed.  Then, start with the second step first and plug $x_2$ right into it.  The $i$th number of the first series will always be equal to the $i-1$th number of the second.  Same convergence.